# Does SpringBoot test with TestRestTemplate always require @SpringBootTest annotation

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spock, spring-boot-test

I am testing a controller using the @WebMvcTest annotation and MockMvc, it is working fine:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

def "test"() {
   def mockRequest = "something"

   when: "we make call"
   def response = mockMvc.perform(post("/getuser")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(mockRequest))
            .andReturn().response

   then: "we get response"
   response.status == OK.value()
   }
}
```

I read some articles online that we can use TestRestTemplate for integration testing.  My question is that if I use TestRestTemplate, do I have to use it with @SpringBootTest annotation for SpringBoot test? The reason I am asking this is that we have many controllers in our springBoot application, and also the service/dao layer code.  It seems that I have to create a TestConfigure.class for all the beans (even the beans for other controllers that I am not testing) for testing purpose, otherwise, I will get error like:

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext 
due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean
```

My test code using TestRestTemplate:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
                classes = [TestConfigure.class])
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class  MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Autowired
TestRestTemplate restTemplate

private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
    return "http://localhost:" + port + uri;
}

def "Integration Success Senario"() {

    given: ""
    when: "we try to get a user using a rest call"

    def request = new User(name, address)

    String jsonResponse = 
       restTemplate.postForObject(createURLWithPort("/getuser"), 
                                  request, String.class)

    .....
   }
 }
```

Comment: Rather than asking if you could workaround the problem you're experiencing, I'd try to fix it. You don't have to create a `TestConfigure` per class. Perhaps we can start from that wrong assumption?

Answer (score 0):

The error just tells you that your integration test is missing a servlet container to run your web service under test. You just have to configure this container somehow. You can do it manually or allow Spring to do it the same way as it does when you use `@SpringBootApplication` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. So just put `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on your integration test class or create test configuration by declaring a static class inside the test and mark put the annotation on it. As suggested in the comment, the following assumption is wrong

> It seems that I have to create a TestConfigure.class for all the beans...

Here is the working example without any user-defined beans and where Spring just returns 404 for non-existing method:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate

    def "Integration Success Senario"() {
        given: ""
        def request = new User("name", "address")

        when: "we try to get a user using a rest call"
        def response = restTemplate.postForObject(createURLWithPort("/getuser"), request, Map.class)

        then:
        response.status == 404

    }

    private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
        return "http://localhost:" + port + uri
    }

    @EnableAutoConfiguration //it configures the servlet container
    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried both (with and without the static class TestConfig) and none of them worked.  When I put @EnableAutoConfiguration on the integration test class, it gave me UnsatisfiedDependencyException complaining about some service/dao class that was used by another controller in the same package as the controller I was trying to test.  That was why I started adding the test configuration beans for those controllers (and their service/dao classes) that I wasn't even testing.

Comment: @jlp maybe you can show us your `TestConfigure` class? Have you tried my example without `TestConfigure`? So we could have some baseline from which it's possible to move further?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your example without `TestConfiguration` by only adding the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, but it gave me UnsatisfiedDependencyException complaining about some service/dao class that was used by another controller in the same package as the controller I was trying to test.  I actually didn't want to have a TestConfiguration class because that class basically defined mock beans which there were so many in our application.